# Rectangles overlapping

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv to draw rectangles over images with the xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax value of the rectangles given in a list.

List of point is

> points = [(1707.0, 1865.0, 2331.0, 2549.0),(1348.0, 1004.0, 1987.0, 1746.0),(749.0, 2129.0, 1674.0, 2939.0)
>            ,(25.0, 1134.0, 1266.0, 2108.0),(253.0, 1731.0, 1403.0, 2449.0)]

```
image = cv2.imread("pathtoimage")
for point in points:
    xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = point
    result_image = cv2.rectangle(image, (int(xmin), int(xmax)), (int(ymin),int(ymax)), (0,255,0), 8)
    os.remove("/home/atul/Documents/CarLabel/imagemapping1-wp-BD489663-BD55-484E-9EA7-EB5662B626B9.png")
    cv2.imwrite("/home/atul/Documents/CarLabel/imagemapping1-wp-BD489663-BD55-484E-9EA7-EB5662B626B9.png",result_image)
```

Rectangles are getting overlapped into each other.
How can I resolve this.

Original Image

[image]

Resulting image

[image]

Comment: The data points are overlapping. How would you like the end result to look?

Comment: the end result should be like rectangles should be drawn where  coordinates get according to point data without overlapping each other.

Comment: Are you generating the points using `boundingRect()` because you need to use `minAreaRect()`if you want to consider rotated boxes... see 7b... https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell no points are generated after user draws rectangle over an object we get x,y coordinates for each 4 points and then finding xmin, ymin, xmax,ymax from those x-y coordinate values.

Comment: Maybe you need `polylines()`... https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html

Comment: How do you know your calculations of `xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax` is correct? Have you drawn a few rectangles by hand to check for overlap?

Comment: @zindarod when user click over object to draw rectangle i get x,y values of all four points. From those values i calculate min & max of x, y for each rectangle. Using this this approach earlier, i got the expected results, this time no luck.

Comment: Post a few points and their corresponding `xmin,ymin,...`.

Answer (score 0):

[`cv2.rectangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga07d2f74cadcf8e305e810ce8eed13bc9) needs the coordintates of *top-left* and *bottom-right* points. So you should use:

```
result_image = cv2.rectangle(image, (int(xmin), int(ymin)), (int(xmax),int(ymax)), (0,255,0), 8)
```

Comment: this also overlapped rectangles